# Bulk delete all terms of certain taxonomy (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I have this code that deletes taxonomies. This code would work, I just don’t know where to paste it to work. Somewhere within wordpress, or phpmyadmin, or where?

```
    $taxonomy_name = 'city';
    $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy_name,
        'hide_empty' => false
    ) );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
               wp_delete_term($term->term_id, $taxonomy_name); 
        }        
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'delete_all_terms' );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be pasted in functions.php (https://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/functions-php/).

But there is a function around your code missing:

```
function delete_all_terms(){
    $taxonomy_name = 'city';
    $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy_name,
        'hide_empty' => false
    ) );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
               wp_delete_term($term->term_id, $taxonomy_name); 
        }        
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'delete_all_terms' );
```

Also be sure to make a backup of your Wordpress database before.

Comment: Carefully, because if you have many terms or posts/producs...this foreach mass delete, could cause timeout from server....